# When and how we should we write the application logs for the execution of stored procedure(Oracle DB)?

Tags: oracle, logging, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to know what are the thumb rules/guidlines to write the logs of a stored procedure(application programs). Normally we use 2 methods:
1) Use UTL_FILE package to write the logs into files(separate files for every run).
2) Use Log4pl package to write the the different logs(dignostic,Error,Warning or Fatal) into a table.
Almost for every procedure we use above 2 methods depending on what we are writing. Like for fatal error we use  Log4pl and for some information display(like which record its processing we write that in file).
Would like to know how other organizations maintaining logs ? Do they also follow aboe 2 methods or they use only one? on what basis its been decided?
Note: I am looking for logs writting only for application programming not for Databse.
Any suggestions or links to blogs would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I prefer a well structured database log to a table, that automatically captures session details such as timestamp, sid, serial#, module, action, client info, current code unit, subprogram, error stack, and elapsed intervals. Then you can get useful reports out of it, which you can't so easily get from a file. A database table is also more easily accessible from the desktop than a file (unless you define an external table over it).

Comment: This is an important question, but probably not a good fit for Stack Overflow, since there are many opinions on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

one more way you can implement logging mechanism in oracle application-
-> [splunk](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/AddOns/released/Oracle/Datatypes)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but i was lookign for something application programing perspective not for the database looging.

Answer (score 0):

UTL_FILE isn't really going to scale well for writing log files, eg

```
SQL> create table log_table (
  2    s timestamp default systimestamp,
  3    m varchar2(1000)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> set timing on
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 10000 loop
  3      insert into log_table (m) values ('My message');
  4      commit;
  5    end loop;
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.62
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    f utl_file.file_type;
  3  begin
  4    f := utl_file.fopen('TMP','logfile.dat','W');
  5    for i in 1 .. 10000 loop
  6      utl_file.put_line(f,to_char(systimestamp)||' '||'My message');
  7      utl_file.fflush(f);
  8    end loop;
  9    utl_file.fclose(f);
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:30.58
```

Now you might be thinking "I'll just remove the utl_file.fflush(f) call" which indeed will make it run in a comparable time to the database table.  But the time when you most need that logging information is when your program crashes - and if it crashes, and you have not flushed, then you run the risk of losing the recent logging information that is critical for knowing why your program crashed.